# node.js mongodb update error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node.js website. I am using mongoose to connect with my mongodb. Adding new records works fine and find also works fine.

But when I update the record it throws the error below. I have a callback function but dont know whats wrong.

throw new Error("writeConcern requires callback")
          ^
Error: writeConcern requires callback

Below is my update code.

```
        var newUser = new User();

        newUser.update({ 'local.email' :  emailID }, { 'local.resetkey': ResetHash }, { multi: false }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
           console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
        });
```

This is my schema...

```
        var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
        var bcrypt      = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
        var crypto      = require('crypto');

        var safe = { w: "0" };

        // define the schema for our user model

            local            : {
                email           : String,
                password        : String,
                resetkey        : String,
                resetexpiry     : String,
            },

        });

        module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `newUser` is a document, but you are calling `update` as it is defined for the model and therefore getting a wrong argument in place of the callback
- Try: `User.update(...` as in the mongoose API docs: `Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);`
- You show incomplete code for your schema.